# complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

How should I show that $$\text{if } k \in \mathcal{L}(X, \mathcal{C}) \text{ with } Rek = 0 \text{, then } k = 0 \text{;}$$

and $$\text{if } k_1 \in \mathcal{L}(X, \mathcal{R}) \text{, then there exists a unique } k \in \mathcal{L}(X, \mathcal{C}) \text{ s. t. } Rek = k_1 \text{?}$$

Do not quite understand it. What is $Rek$? Any help?

Comment: You should give a link to the text and more context. It could be $Re(z)$, the real part of $z\in \Bbb C$.

Comment: Rek(x) = 0 means that Rek maps the real part of complex vector to 0. But how can we say k maps every complex vector to 0?

Comment: What are $X$ and $\mathcal{L}(X,\mathcal{C})$? My guess is that $X$ is some space and the latter is a collection of functions from $X$ to $\Bbb{C}$. But, really, you should not keep us in the dark. And my first guess can't be right because the constant function $-i$ certainly has a vanishing real part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Re(k)(x)$ is the real part of $k(x)$. For the fisrt part note that $0=Re(k(ix))=Re(ik(x))=-Im (k(x)$. Hence $Re(k(x))=Im(k(x))=0$ which gives $k(x)=0$.

For the second part define $k(x)=k_1(x)-ik_1(ix)$. I leave it to you to verify that $k$ is in $\mathcal L(X,\mathbb C)$ and Re(k)=k_1$. Uniqueness follows from first part.

Comment: Thanks, but why can we have Re(ik(x)) = - Im(k(x))?

Comment: @Kevin For any complex number $a+ib$ we have $Re(i(a+ib))=Re(ia-b)=-b=-Im(a+ib)$.

Comment: @Kevin it is given that $Re(k(x))=0$ for all $x$. We can replace $x$ by $ix$ to get $-Im(k(x))=Re i(k(x))=Re k(ix)=0$.